# How is Einstein-Bose condensation supposed to stabilize d*(2380)?

Tags: dark-matter, quarks, bose-einstein-condensate

[A recent paper](https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/1361-6471/ab67e8) suggests a new dark matter candidate: Einstein-Bose condensates of the [hexaquark/dibaryon](https://arxiv.org/abs/1610.05591) [d*(2380)](https://journals.aps.org/prl/pdf/10.1103/PhysRevLett.112.202301?casa_token=98MZlPG_2_QAAAAA%3AAm8J5rsN8Jf3K3I-74wRP0QeAAI6_YNYCQlTQ8sQh-GBFEysfavxNu0m_RCJc1CnkO0xTC5fPl91raw) ($uuuddd$). The nice thing about this theory is that it does not require any new physics, just that during Big Bang the densities are high enough for the hexaquarks to form condensates.

My problem with this is that free d*(2380) appears to have a lifespan of $10^{-23}$ s. So clearly joining the BEC must extend the lifespan tremendously. My question is: how?

Comment: It seems to me that all the talk of $d^*$ and Bose-Einstein condensation is a big red herring: there is nothing magical that Bose-Einstein condensation does (in particular, the quarks themselves don't care about this low-energy description, since they're fermions), standard quantum mechanics still applies, and the real question is whether a bound state of many quarks can be stable.

Comment: The answer is "maybe", and that hypothesis is known as quark nuggets. But nobody considers them as a dark matter candidate because they interact, well, strongly. The closest clear exposition of this idea is [Dark Quark Nuggets (2018)](https://arxiv.org/abs/1810.04360), which uses dark quarks which don't interact strongly with the regular ones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bose condensation does not really have anything to do with the (possible) stability of D* matter. The paper assumes that a miracle happens, and D* matter is so tightly bound that the binding energy per particle-pair is bigger than the mass difference between the D* and a deuteron, and as a result D* matter is absolutely stable.

The proposed state is a Bose condensate simple because it is a systems of Bosons at essentially zero temperature. The idea of Bose condensation of bosonic multi-hadrons is not in itself crazy, Bose condensates of deuterons or alpha are likely to exist (but with much smaller binding energies).

However, if D* matter is indeed bound by several hundred MeV per particle (the miracle assumed above), then the interaction would have to be quite strong, the density would have to be quite large (several times larger than ordinary nuclear matter density), and there is no obvious sense in which this is a Bose condensate of approximately point-like D* particles. This is really absolutely stable, non-strange quark matter, an idea that gets tossed around every so often (which has no experimental evidence in favor, and very little theoretical support).